# `Jupyter-book build` taking too much RAM when building 4.5K notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterbook

### Background

I have preprocessed over 4.5K `jupyter notebooks`.

I would like to use `jupyter-book` to build a book from the processed notebooks.

I have execute_notebooks: "off" in my `jupyter-book` configs.

However, when I run `jupyter-book build` on the notebooks, I run into an error with the RAM required: the RAM required keeps on increasing.

### Questions

**QS1. Is there something that I should be doing to avoid this RAM increase? Maybe something in my config/toc ymls?**

**QS2. Alternatively, is there any way I can estimate how much time/mem will be needed to build the book before running `jupyter-book build?**

### Extra

Below is a graph of the mem usage in 1hr of processing (when logs are at `writing output... [  3%] content/toi_notebooks/toi_2175`)

[image: image of mem usage in 1hr]

`_toc.yml`:

```yaml
format: jb-book
root: index
parts:
  - chapters:
    - file: content/example_loader
    - file: citation
    - file: content/toi_fits
      sections:
        - glob: content/toi_notebooks/toi_*
```

`_config.yml`

```yaml
# in _config.yml
title: "TESS Atlas"
author: the TESS Atlas community
logo: _static/atlas_logo.png
execute:
  execute_notebooks: "off"

# Define the name of the latex output file for PDF builds
latex:
  latex_documents:
    targetname: book.tex

html:
  use_edit_page_button: false
  use_repository_button: true
  use_issues_button: true

# Information about where the book exists on the web
repository:
  url: https://github.com/dfm/tess-atlas
  branch: main
```

**gitissue:** https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyter-book/issues/1571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all `matplotlib-inline` plots and rendering images in markdown cells (with `![]()`) has fixed this issue for me. The inline-plots make the notebooks much larger due to the text representation of the image.